# Will a Vancouver Day Pass Work in Victoria?

Tags: public-transport, canada, vancouver, british-columbia

If I buy a day pass in Vancouver, hop on a ferry to Victoria, and arrive there, can I use the day pass to get around Victoria?

We're heading to Butchart Gardens from Burnaby.

Comment: I don't think "hopping on a ferry to Victoria" is such a hop. Ferries don't serve Victoria directly, nor do they serve Vancouver directly. And the trip still takes 3 to 4 hours ([4 by bus](http://www.pacificcoach.com/Bus-Coach-Travel/Crosswater/Vancouver-to-Victoria)).

Comment: Burnaby to Butchart Gardens (and back?) by public transport and ferry is going to make for a *really* long day. It might not even be possible in a single day. By car, with no traffic and no wait for the ferry, would take at least 3 hours one way.

Comment: Just went from Burnaby to Butchart Gardens while missing a bus stop by several dozen kilometers.  Totally doable but yes, a *really* long day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The passes for Vancouver and Victoria are different. 
I went two weeks ago from Vancouver to Victoria by bus and ferry. On the ferry
you can buy in the gift shop a daily pass for buses in Victoria, costs 5 CAD.
To add: you can do it in one day.